# How to create non linear axis in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot a series of datas and get a result as below

[image]

But I'm expecting to have a non linear axis as below.

[image]

How can I make that kind of plot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the code you have written ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the y-axis to logaritmic by writing `plt.yscale('log')`

full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
example = [pow(2,i) for i in range(10)]
plt.plot(example)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: See also documentation here : http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#logarithmic-and-other-nonlinear-axis

Answer (score 3):

You can use `plt.semilogy`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.semilogy([i**2 for i in range(100)])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]